# How to delete dll from webapp/bin

Tags: 2007, delete

I have a dll which was deployed by wsp to bin directory ...webapp/bin, now i removed the solution and i want to install it again, i cannot because this dll i kind a locked.

So i went to delete it manually, but i get an error saying "Access denied", that it is either the disk is protected of write operations or the dll is being used.

So I restarted like al the services, i did iisreset /stop ... but still cannot delete the dll, anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

**Not recommeneded way of doing it but I do it this way.**

Open Command prompt, type "iisreset" as soon as you type it, go to folder and delete the dll.

I used to do it on a demo environment, if you want to do it on production make sure you to have some downtime sorted first.

Answer (score 0):

```
•Open a command prompt
•Navigate to the location where the locked file is
•Press CTRL-ALT-DEL, click on “task manager”, select the Processes tab
•Kill the explorer.exe process via the “End Process” button
•Go back to the command prompt and delete the file
•Bring up the task manager windows again
•Select file->new task
•Type explorer.exe in the “create new task” field
•Press OK.
```

Hope it helps
[Source](http://www.geeksaresexy.net/2007/06/04/how-to-delete-an-undeletable-file/)